# .htaccess Rewrite rule cause css, js stop working

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know that this is common issue but I could not find a solution at SO for my issue

The htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and the index.php just contains a `require` to index.html where the html exists.

I have tried to use `/` at my css relative paths but nothing change. Also I used `<base href="/">`  but nothing change too. The directive

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

also do not fix the problem.

**UPDATE. PROBLEM SOLVED**

I checked error logs where the error `variable ${REQUEST_FILENAME} is not defined` displayed. So changing `$` to `%` at `.htaccess` fix the problem

Comment: I took a look at access.log but I could not find something interesting.

Comment: At my last 8 logs (my last request) display a 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in Apache httpd 2.2.16 and later there's a new directive which was created for exactly this scenario. It's called FallbackResource. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

In your case, you want:

```
FallbackResource /app/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all the link in the page are fully defined

```html
<head>
  <link href="http://yoursite.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://yoursite.com/script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

if you only have `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` it won't work after after using .htaccess.

Comment: will not help me to have absolute paths for resources because I am developing at a develop environment and when the applications goes live all the links will have to be changed...